# ef error:{"A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'ShippingCardID'."}

Tags: entity-framework

I work in EF.Xml definition table is ...

```
    <EntityType Name="ShippingCards">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ShippingCardID" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="ShippingCardID" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
      <Property Name="ProducedID" Type="int" />
      <Property Name="User" Type="int" />
      <Property Name="Count" Type="int" />
    </EntityType>
```

methode is definition

```
    public void addProduct(Product product)
    {
        ShippingCard sc = new ShippingCard();
        sc.ProducedID = product.ProductID;
        Add(sc);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

When you try to put in the product in the cart breaks my mistake

**{"A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'ShippingCardID'."}**

InnerError:
**{"A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'ShippingCardID'."}**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have incorrectly defined relations between entities. This error says that `ShippingCardID` is used as foreign key (= dependent property) in some relation which is not allowed because only properties with `StoreGeneratedPattern.None` can be used as foreign keys.

Comment: When you try to enter my product to cart iam columns to 0, do not pull a good value